# I am using pypdf I try to open pdf document . Pdf document cannot opened at error files as it throws WARNING:pypdf._reader:EOF marker not found

Tags: python, pypdf, data-preprocessing, pdf-reader, pdfdocument

To process pdf documents I am opening opening pdf document using

```
 input_pdf = PdfReader(open(input_pdf_path, "rb"))
```

In my case some files are not properly written so by manual opening itself the pdf document cannot be opened. it shows

> WARNING:pypdf._reader:EOF marker not found

so i tried to catch that particular warnings so I can put that warning into exception

a) with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as warn_list:
b)        input_pdf = PdfReader(open(input_pdf_path, "rb"))

```
# Process any warnings captured during the 'with' block
for warning_item in warn_list:
    # Check for the specific warning you want to catch
    if "EOF marker not found" in str(warning_item.message):
        print(f"Warning: {warning_item.message}")
        # Raise an exception to exit the function
        raise Exception("EOF marker not found warning")
```

But after it comes to b) line, it goes to a) line and pausing like still executing for a long time and not showing any improvement of executing next line code or raise exception .

I just want to catch execption and update it to the table as per my requirements

Comment: Since you have a [malformed pdf](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2009/05/14/malformed-pdf-documents/), have you tried to simply add a `%%EOF` at the end of your pdf? Be aware that it could be tricky, I leave [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14598490/10301322) that could be related

Comment: I suggest trying another Python library that can recover from trivial errors by repairing them on the fly - i.e. PyMuPDF (I am a maintainer).

Comment: but in pymupdf it read a words as as sentence . So if I am extracting information it will be present at the very next line not at the same line.

The fox looks I am expert --> this is line in a document 

in pymupdf it takes as 
(the fox )              in first line
(i am)                    in second line 
(expert)                   in third line 

it converts text document as this
so I need to iterate to n number of lines to get the info not at the very same line itself.

But advantage of pymupdf is very very fast